# Laravel 5 pass data from controller to command

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to pass an array from my controller to my command. See code below

```
Queue::push(new SendReminderPush(),array('data' => $data));
```

But when I call the command I always get an exception.

Missing argument 1 for App\Commands\SendReminderPush::handle()

This is my handle function in the command class:

```
public function handle($data){
   foreach($data as $d){
    do something
   }
}
```

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should the data you pass not be a parameter of the class when you instantiate it? `Queue::push(new SendReminderPush(['data' => $data]));` Then assign them to vars in your constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Laravel 5 this actually depends on what `$data` is. If it is an array and you want to have Laravel map it automatically you would do something like this:

```
$this->dispatchFromArray('App\Commands\SendReminderPush', $data);
```

Say your `$data` looks like this as well:

```
$data = array('name' => 'Test', 'email' => 'test@example.com');
```

In your `SendReminderPush` you would then map that in the constructor:

```
public function __construct($name, $email) {
   $this->name = $name;
   $this->email = $email;
}
```

You would then handle it in the command (if it is a self handling command) like this:

```
public function handle(){
   $this->doSomething($this->name);
}
```

I would look at how the Command Bus works in Laravel 5 more. Check it out [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this one but I get another exception.
Undefined property: App\Commands\SendReminderPush::$device_token

Here is my constructor:
public function __construct($device_token,$message)
 {
  $this->device_token=$device_token;
  $this->message=$message;
 }
And that's how I dispatch:
$this->dispatchFromArray('App\Commands\SendReminderPush', $data);

Comment: is it possible to access this data from the handle function instead of the constructor! just because the class will look weird if the data if the handl function are defined in the constructor parameter while the class dependencies are defined in the handl function parameter!